# Google Earth places placemarks at wrong location

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have been trying to locate the place marks of the data I logged.
I used the following KML code to locate my points as Placemarks.Unfortunately and Surprisingly the points are placed at wrong location.I am just wondering if there is any error in my KML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns = "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
<Style id="icon_id">
 <IconStyle>
<Icon>
   <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-blank.png</href>
   <scale>1.0</scale>
  </Icon>
 </IconStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
  <name>04-02-2015</name>
  <description>Points</description>
  <styleUrl>#icon_id</styleUrl>
  <Point>
   <coordinates>39.6495820075,-79.96055352125</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
  <name>04-02-2015</name>
  <description>Points</description>
  <styleUrl>#icon_id</styleUrl>
  <Point>
   <coordinates>39.649492665,-79.96053303</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I also tried locating the points manually on Google Earth and they show the location perfectly.But when I try running the KML code it screws me.

p.s. The points are supposed to be in WV,US while Google Earth Places it at some place in Antarctica.

I used Android LocationManager API to log my latitude and longitude values.

Comment: Compare the coordinate systems of the points you logged with the coordinate system that Google Earth uses.  Most likely the two are not in the same map projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its a map Projection.

I went through the following link https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148110?hl=en and as suggested used a tool available at http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx to convert my coordinates and worked.

The change made was writing in the order  `<coordinates>longitude,latitude</coordinates>` instead of

`<coordinates>latitude, longitude</coordinates>`  from the (latitude,longitude) pair generated by Android Location Manager API.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Android Location Manager API.  A better forum for your question may be another Stack Exchange  site:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sound like you may have solved the problem.

Comment: Yup with your help . Thanks Mike!!